# Making BroadcastReceiver work in the background in API 26 or above

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I recently asked a question about an app that I made, and whose BroadcastReceiver I had registered in the Manifest, something that is prohibited in API level 26 and above. I received great answers to help resolve the problem, one of them being that I declare the BroadcastReceiver in the activity itself, with the intent filters and registering done right there programmatically.

***Here is the link to my question:***
[Dialog doesn't appear after system broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302590/dialog-doesnt-appear-after-system-broadcast?noredirect=1#comment89582378_51302590)

I did do this in a similar app that I made earlier, but my purpose of making this is to not detect ringer mode changes when the app is running, but to listen to them when the app is not running, meaning that the specific activity of the app is started as soon as the system broadcast initiates. **Therefore, I would like to know how to do this, i.e., make the BroadcastReceiver receive system broadcasts in devices running API 26 or more if I can't register the receiver in the manifest to do that.**

*P.S. I tested the app in a device running Android API level 25 and it worked perfectly as it should have, it's just that I am in the search for an alternative to this technique for newer APIs.*

Answer (score 1):

> but to listen to them when the app is not running, meaning that the specific activity of the app is started as soon as the system broadcast initiates

For broadcasts that are not on [the implicit broadcast whitelist](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), you would need to have a foreground service that registers for those broadcasts via `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the methodical process of doing this? Also, wouldn’t a service take up more battery than the broadcast receiver?

Comment: @AqibAhmed: "Can you please elaborate on the methodical process of doing this?" -- please explain what you do not understand. For example, foreground services are covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground). "wouldn’t a service take up more battery than the broadcast receiver?" -- no, but it would take up more system RAM.

Comment: will the use of a foreground service start the app when it is not running as soon as the system broadcasts a change in ringer mode?

Comment: @AqibAhmed: If your foreground service is running, that means that your app is already running. For you to receive implicit broadcasts like this, your foreground service needs to be running *all the time*. That is difficult to achieve in general, and it means that your app will be consuming system RAM all the time.

Comment: but isn’t there any other way around this? I mean I love the simplicity till API 26, but this doesn’t seem as efficient as it should’ve been.

Comment: @AqibAhmed: "but isn’t there any other way around this?" -- none that I know of. And, if one is found, that would represent a bug that would need to get fixed. Google does not want apps responding to most system broadcasts, unless those apps are running for other reasons. I have some more notes on the implicit broadcast ban [in this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html).

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for taking out the time and answering my stupid questions.

Comment: Sir, why shouldn't I use a background service instead of a foreground service, which I could start at phone boot?

Comment: @AqibAhmed: Because a background service can only run for 1 minute on Android 8.0+.